# Android set theme for view that created by service

Tags: android

in service

```
new MyView(this);
```

view class

```
public class MyView extends LinearLayout {
public MyView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.view, this, true);
}
```

how to set theme for this view? thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I know it's almost 4 years late but i had the same problem. 
ContextThemeWrapper class is what you're looking for. You need to instantiate your custom view with ContextThemeWrapper like this:

```
MyView(context = ContextThemeWrapper(this /* your service */, R.style.AppTheme))
```

Comment: How can I instantiate like this?

Answer (score 1):

@MertNYuksel's answer worked for me and I can use Material Theme on View generated by service. In case @Ahmad still wondering on how to instantiate the Context

```
class Window(private val context: ContextWrapper //before was Context) {
        layoutInflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        // error under this line before using ContextWrapper
        mView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_window, null)
}

override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        // create the custom or default notification
        // based on the android version
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) startMyOwnForeground() else startForeground(
            1,
            Notification())

        // before was val window = Window(this) <- generate error combination below
        val window = Window(ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.Theme_AppTheme))

    }
```

my error lines were this

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12 in com.package.name:layout/popup_window: Binary XML file line #12 in com.package.name/popup_window: Error inflating class <unknown>
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12 in com.package.name/popup_window: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

and under that inflating error, I found this

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).
```

posting this to help with google search, because I can't find similar error combinations (in case anyone got the same error when using MaterialTheme for floating window/view generated by foreground service).

Comment: @GhasemSoleimani This does answer the question. You've probably misunderstood the answer by reading it too quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you set your theme in XML by using the style="@style/Theme" attribute

Comment: it doesn't work. any other suggestions, Dominic D'Souza?

Comment: because view is created by service?

Comment: that should not matter ...are you saying that when u specify the theme in xml and create the view from activity you get a different theme